# Render Image into subclassed QDeclarativeItem using OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qt4, opengl-es-2.0, qml

I am trying to perform several image manipulations using OpenGL ES 2.0 and display the output into a subclassed QDeclarativeItem which will then be used within my QML GUI.
I read through the answers found here: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/4109
and succeeded in drawing a red-to-blue colored rectangle within my QML GUI by overriding the paint() methode of the QDeclarativeItem:

```
void GLDeclarativeItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->beginNativePainting();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3ub(0,0,255);
    glVertex2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(0, height());
    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    glVertex2d(width(), height());
    glVertex2d(width(), 0);
    glEnd();
    painter->endNativePainting();
}
```

However, what I am trying to achieve is to draw the image which will be handled within my custom QGLWidget as the content of the above described QDeclarativeItem (instead of the red-to-blue colored content).

Within my custom QGLWidget I am using:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

for drawing, which worked fine. However, I can not find the conversion between the drawing within my GLWidget and my GLDeclarativeItem. All the things I have tried so far just gave me a rectangle without any content at all.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar thing, but solved differently: I used an **overlay**.

I simply put the **OpenGL rendering in its own widget which is placed on top of the QDeclarativeView.**

This works quite well, although you cannot draw ontop of the OpenGL rendering. If you should really need to, stack over another QML view with a translucent background.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Helmut, sounds promising. Although I am not sure how i can add a widget as overlay to a QDeclarativeView. Do you have any code to help me out? Can be pretty abstract, just to give me a hint. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, the idea is like this: I guess you used a `QDeclarativeView *myview`. Then do `QGLWidget * myglwidget = new QGLWidget(myview)` (using your own QGLWidget subclass) and position it accordingly. That way, `myglwidget` is a child of `myview`, while not being a real `QGraphicsItem`. Does this help you?